# Fetch file from specific directory where jar file is placed

Tags: java, relative-path

I want to fetch a text file from the directory where my jar file is placed.

Assuming my desktop application 'foo.jar' file is placed in d:\ in an installation of Windows.
There is also a test.txt file in the same directory which I want to read when 'foo.jar' application is running.
How can fetch that particular path in my 'foo.jar' application?
In short I want to fetch the path of my 'foo.jar' file where it is placed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, that actual code does depend on actual class location within your package, but in general it could look like:

```
URL root = package.Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
String path = (new File(root.toURI())).getParentFile().getPath();
...
// handle file.txt in path
```

Comment: Hey it's grate but still I couldn't read test.txt file. do have any idea?

Comment: @Nirav: try echoing `path` to stdout, it will make things easier to understand; you may also have to place `file.txt` to your `build` path for testing.

Comment: @Nirav: what is the result of `System.out.println(path)`?

Comment: path of the build folder.C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build

Comment: @Nirav: good :) Now try running the jar from your `dist` path (like `java -jar projectroot\dist\foo.jar` and see the result. The point is that Netbeans runs the code not from resultant .jar, but from non-packaged `build` directory. Since this method rely on `Main` class location, it will produce different results when this calss is packaged within jar or not.

Comment: This time output is something like this:"Path of file==============>C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\NetBeans
Projects\IVRS Java Source Code\dist"

Comment: @Nirav: correct, i.e. the path to your jar, isn't it? :) Once again, if you need to test your app from IDE, you could copy `file.txt` to your `build` path (e.g. with ant task).

Comment: yes, It is path of my jar file. but though error is occured during the file fetching.

Comment: Hey bro. It's done. I just need to replace single \ with \\  and it's working fine....Thanks for support.

Comment: hey look at my own answer of this question it's very simple and just 1 line code.

Comment: @Nirav: nope, they are not equivalent, unless you change statement "I want to fetch a text file from the directory where my jar file is placed" to ".. from user working directory"

Comment: yes I got your point. Vinit reynolds told me why. He posted comment on my own answer of this question. It's really important thing.

Answer (score 1):

Most JARs are loaded using a URLClassLoader that remembers the codesource from where the JAR has been loaded. You may use this knowledge to obtain the location of the directory from where the JAR has been loaded by the JVM. You can also use the ProtectionDomain class to get the CodeSource (as shown in the other answer; admittedly, that might be better).

The location returned is often of the `file:` protocol type, so you'll have to remove this protocol identifier to get the actual location. Following is a short snippet that performs this activity; you might want to build in more error checking and edge case detection, if you need to use it in production:

```
public String getCodeSourceLocation() {
        ClassLoader contextClassLoader = CurrentJARContext.class.getClassLoader();
        if(contextClassLoader instanceof URLClassLoader)
        {
            URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader)contextClassLoader;
            URL[] urls = classLoader.getURLs();
            String externalForm = urls[0].toExternalForm();
            externalForm = externalForm.replaceAll("file:\\/", "");
            externalForm = externalForm.replaceAll("\\/", "\\" + File.separator);
            return externalForm;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the shortest answer of my own question.
**String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");**

Comment: That works only if you start the java executable from the same directory.

Comment: sorry I couldn't get can you please explain with example.

Comment: If you launch your app as `java -jar D:>aJAR.jar` from `C:>`, user.dir will contain `C:>` and not `D:>`.

Comment: Yes bro you are absolutely right....Thanks to draw my attention this small but very important point.

Comment: But if Run jar by double click in window os then it's okay?